# $ \left\lfloor 10^{\lfloor n \rfloor} \pi \bmod 10 \right\rfloor $ - does this function give the nth decimal place of pi?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions, pi, rounding-error, desmos

Function to round the nth decimal place of pi to the nearest integer. For example, for pi, n = 0, y = 3. n = 1, y = 1. n = 2, y = 4. And so on and so forth.

Gives me good results until n = 17, which yields 8 instead of the expected 3. Then it's unfortunately kind of all over the place. It only gives me even numbers?

Is my function correct, or is this a Desmos error?

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bekze2iayc

Comment: Please avoid having your subject line consist of nothing but MathJax. It messes up some navigation shortcuts.

Comment: Dealt with, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this function is correct, computer software tends to only have a finite number of digits represented.

Comment: Oops, my mistake.

Comment: As $n$ is an integer you will have $\lfloor n \rfloor = n$ so you could write this more simply as $\lfloor 10^n\pi \pmod{10}\rfloor$.  Also $\pmod {10}$ is not actually a mathematical function but a notation for equivalence classes it'd probably cleaner and stylistically to write it as $\lfloor 10^n\pi\rfloor \pmod{10}$.  You function is almost by definition the $n$th digit of $\pi$.  This is simply Desmos's rounding error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is mathematically correct, but not computerically correct.  $64$ bit [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) have about $16$ decimal digits of precision.  You don't need the floor on $n$, but you are trying to extract decimal digits that are not there.